# How to pass props to component inside a React Navigation navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass props to a component that has been wrapped through a call to `create...Navigator` call, i.e.

```
// Search.js
const Navigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Wines,
    Stores,
    Vineyards,
    Restaurants
});

// Somewhere in render()...
<Navigator />
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pass parameters to the `Wines` / `Stores` / etc. components from the `Search` component (above). I've [read the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) and apparently this can be done easily with `navigation.navigate` by passing in an object, but I'm not sure how to do it with this particular method. Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you trying to make a search screen like instagram? A searchBar and below tabs with different solutions, and you want to pass the search criteria down to tabs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your example is a bit vague so I try to explain as much as I can.

There is 2 different ways to pass properties to screens *(except redux implementation)*.

### 1) [`navigate`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens) action

You can pass parameters to navigated screen with passing `params` argument to the screen.

> navigation.navigate({routeName, params, action, key}) OR
>   navigation.navigate(routeName, params, action)
>
> **routeName** - A destination routeName that has been registered somewhere in the app's router
>
> **params** - Params to merge into the destination route
>
> **action** - (advanced) The sub-action to run in the child router, if the screen is a navigator. See Actions Doc for a full list of
>   supported actions.
>
> **key** - Optional identifier of what route to navigate to. Navigate back to this route, if it already exists

**Sample**

```
this.props.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Brent' })
```

### 2) [`screenProps`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props)

You can pass a global parameter to the navigation which can be available in every screen for that navigation.

> **screenProps** - Pass down extra options to child screens

**Sample**

```
const SomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  // config
});

<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

I have created a small sample app which I am guessing you are trying to achieve.

```
const Tab = ({name, searchValue}) => (
  <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
    <Text>{name}</Text>
    <Text>{`Searching: ${searchValue || '...'}`}</Text>
  </View>
);

const Wines = (props) => (<Tab name="Wines Page" searchValue={props.screenProps.searchValue} />);
const Stores = (props) => (<Tab name="Stores Page" searchValue={props.screenProps.searchValue} />);
const Vineyards = (props) => (<Tab name="Vineyards Page" searchValue={props.screenProps.searchValue} />);
const Restaurants = (props) => (<Tab name="Restaurants Page" searchValue={props.screenProps.searchValue} />);

const Navigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Wines,
    Stores,
    Vineyards,
    Restaurants
});

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ''
  }
  changeText = (text) => {
    this.setState({text})
  }
  clearText = () => {
    this.setState({text: ''})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SearchBar
          lightTheme
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={this.changeText}
          onClearText={this.clearText}
          placeholder='Type Here...' />
        <Navigator screenProps={{searchValue: this.state.text}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to use Redux to get around React-navigations awful architecture. Or use Wix's React-native-navigation which is much better, has 'passProps'.

Comment: screenProps has been removed in react-navigation 5 https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/pull/5

Answer (score 22):

Based on [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7764) you can pass properties to screens also like this:

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home">
                {(props) => <HomeScreen  {...props} text={homeText} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
           <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

The difference to the following method from the docs

```
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

is this:

```
            <Tab.Screen name="Home">
                {(props) => <HomeScreen  {...props} text={homeText} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
```

This worked just fine for me in a similar case.

Comment: accurate answer